# How can I turn a TypeRep into a String?

Tags: haskell

Iside ghci, I can do

```
import Data.Typeable
typeOf ""
```

which shows

```
[Char]
```

as expected. The actual type of the return value of the typeOf function is `TypeRep`, as we can see by

```
:t typeOf ""
```

I would like (for debugging purpose) to output the result of `typeOf` using `putStrLn` inside a `do` calculation, but for this, I need a String. Is there a way to convert that `TypeRep` into a something which can be fed into `putStrLn`?

Comment: You can use `show`, or `print` (to print it).

Comment: Thanks. If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it. So, `print` always implicitly applies `show` to its argument?

Comment: `print` is defined as `print x = putStrLn (show x)`, so it will call `show`, and then use `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 6):

`TypeRep` is an alias of [**`SomeTypeRep`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#t:SomeTypeRep), it is an instance of the [**`Show`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Show.html#t:Show). You thus can print this with:

```
putStrLn (show (typeOf ""))
```

or use [**`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) which is `putStrLn . show`:

```
print (typeOf "")
```